# Python listener shuts down after reading all data if socket is still open

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm writing a socket listener in python with the following code:

```
    self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.sock.bind((HOST,PORT))
    self.sock.listen(10)
    print('Listening...')

    try:
        while 1:
            conn, addr = self.sock.accept()
            print('Connection accepted from %s' % addr[0])

            curr_thread = GenericListenerThread(conn, addr)
            curr_thread.start()              

    except Exception as E:
        pass
```

This accepts the connection, then spins up a new thread and feeds it the socket created from accept() and the address.

And in the GenericListenerThread class I have:

```
class GenericListenerThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, conn, addr):
        self.conn = conn
        self.addr = addr

        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
            self.read_socket()


    def read_socket(self):
        data = "data"
        socket_data = []
        try:
            while len(data) > 0:
    >>>>        data = self.conn.recv(4096)
                socket_data.append(data)
        except Exception as E:
            pass

        for i in range(0, len(socket_data)):
            socket_data[i] = socket_data[i].decode('utf-8')

        self.message = "".join(socket_data)
```

(There's actually more, but this is all that's actually relevant)

And on the client side, I have just a test script:

```
import socket


mystr = 'aString'
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1',2358))

s.sendall(mystr.encode('utf-8'))
print('sent')
temp = b''
print('about to receive')
while True:
    data = s.recv(4096)
    if not data: break    
    temp = temp.decode('utf-8') + data.decode('utf-8')
    print(temp)

print('received')
temp = temp.decode('utf-8') + data.decode('utf-8')
print(temp)
```

When debugging, my "client" gets to "about to receive". Putting breakpoints in the listener code gets me to the line denoted with ">>>". Once it has tried to read it twice (I assume until it's finished reading all the data, so it would be 3x if it was >4096 bytes) the code just drops off. I have try/excepts every where with breakpoints in the excepts, but nothing happens. It might be that the thread is dying - I'm not sure how to tell.

So, the code that actually gets executed in the `read_socket` function is:

```
data = "data"
socket_data = []
data = self.conn.recv(4096)
socket_data.append(data)
data = self.conn.recv(4096)
```

And then my code just drops off the face of the earth when I would expect the following to occur after the above:

```
socket_data.append(data)
<checks while loop, sees we're done>
for in in range(0, len(socket_data):
   ......
```

However, if in the client I add `s.close()` after the `s.sendall...` line it works fine, but when it tried to send the response the client has stopped listening.

So I guess my question is: How do I successfully read all the data from this socket while keeping my thread alive so that I can send a response?

EDIT:

To clarify the issue is that once all the data gets read the Thread seems to just die off, and none of the rest of the code gets executed. Thus, the `for` loop in the `read_socket` function never gets executed, so I'm unable to even make a response to send back. However if, on the client, I add `s.close()`, everything goes as expected.

Comment: It works as excpected or I don't understand. The listener receives `b'aString'` and then `recv` blocks the execution until any other data is received. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I'm trying to keep that connection open so that I can send more data to the client

Comment: The connection is still open, just use `self.conn.send`. Since you're using threads, consider creating another one to accomplish that.

Comment: The issue is that I can't get to the rest of the code in my thread once everything is received (or attempted). I'll add an edit to the bottom of the question

Comment: I don't think your thread dies. The `recv` function is just blocking the execution, so the code behind that call never gets called. That explains why it works when adding `s.close()`, because `recv` raises an exception (which you're just passing) and then the program flow continues.

Comment: So then I suppose my question is how to I get past that `recv` function so that the rest of my thread can run?

Comment: You can convert the data to utf8 as long as you receive it (right where you're now doing the append), instead of inserting them into a list to process it later. If you need to send data at the same time then consider using another thread for that (one for input and one for output).